# Advantages of Mac OS X Server over Mac OS X Client?

Tags: macos, mac, mac-mini, osx-server

I'm debating buying a mac mini with the regular client OS or the model with the server os for the purposes of replacing my home server.  Are there any advantages for such a use with the server os?

Comment: Should be on serverfault.

Comment: If you have to ask then you probably don't need the server.

Comment: @Josh K:  Nope, Server Fault is for pros.  This is a guy with a home server, and this doesn't look like a question a pro would ask.  Super User is the right place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are advantages and disadvantages, of course. Should you buy the server version? As always, the answer is, "it depends." Do you need to run any of the following?

- [Mail server](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/mail-services.html)
- [Calendar server](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/ical-server.html)
- [Address book server](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/addressbook-server.html)
- [File server](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/file-sharing.html)
- [Podcast production](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/podcast-producer.html)
- [Wiki hosting](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/wiki-server.html)
- [Web hosting](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/web-hosting.html)
- [Centralized Spotlight search](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/spotlight-server.html)
- [Centralized management](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/client-management.html)
- [VPN Server](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/networking-vpn.html)

Most or all of these features are available in free, open source products (in fact, many of them are based on the open source projects).  You can add [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/), [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/), [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/), [Samba](http://www.samba.org/), [Calendar Server](http://trac.calendarserver.org/), etc. to a client Mac OS X installation if you want.  However, [Mac OS X Server wraps them up into a nice, aesthetic, easy-to-administer package](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/).  This could be a net positive or negative to you depending on what you want from this machine.

By purchasing a Mac mini server, the extra hard drive is nice but you sacrifice the DVD drive.  This might be a deal breaker depending on what else you plan to use this home server for.  You can always add an external one, but that is extra cost and hassle.  Again, it's a trade-off.

Comment: It sounds pointless for me to use it as it only seems to add centralized management interface (don't know how I missed that link).  I'm guessing that Server would be nice for a small business needing Web hosting, wiki hosting, calendar server, mail server, etc.  My purposes are primarily for: attaching a firewire 800 external RAID5 enclosure, using as a central iTunes/AppleTV server, recording ATSC TV, and running a cctv monitor. I'll probably use Apache for internal things, but nothing that can't be done with the standard OS. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something really cool.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you use your current server for, the client OS Mini may fit all your necessary needs.

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_os_server) lists the features of the server OS. I know that some of these can be added to the client version if necessary. Also the clientOS Mini comes with iLife.

I use mine(clientOS model) as a media storage/server with a couple of large disks running in a firewire 800 enclosure, which fits my needs nicely.

Comment: You're doing exactly what I'm going for.  Right now, I'm running Ubuntu with a RAID1 array for data. After a disappointingly complex adventure in setting up AFP on Ubuntu and now that I've outgrown my RAID1 array and am looking to expand beyond a pair of disks, I'm looking at alternatives.  The only thing I found disappointing about the Mac Mini is the lack of eSata, but when the drives are primarily shared over a network it makes little difference if it's eSata or Firewire 800.

Comment: well, in addition to the slower bus, the drives themselves are WD Green drives that run at 5900 rpm. For basic file storage and iTunes library, this is plenty fast.